# If $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$\ $A$ , A is finite and $f^2$ is a rational function then $f$ is a rational function.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> If $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$\ $A$ , A is finite and $f^2$ is a rational function, then $f$ is a rational function.

You can use perhaps that if A is empty and $f^2$ is a polynomial then $f$ is too a polynomial.

Comment: What you need is that if $f$ has an essential isolated singularity at a point, then $f^2$ also has an essential singularity there. What would imply that?

Comment: Note that the finiteness of $A$ cannot be simply eliminated, as taking $f$ to be a branch of the square root function with standard cut along the non-positive real axis show.